# Show business days in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

I'm not sure if this topic is appropriate for SU, if not please just tell me I'll delete my own thread :)

I have searched on internet but results are not for what I want to do. I want to show business days since the start of whatever month is displayed in my Outlook calendar. I do not want to show business days as in having a weekly view from monday to friday.

I'll give you an example just to be clear:

Today we are friday the 22nd, it is the 16th business day in the month. How could I display 16 in today's box in the calendar, 17 next tuesday (next monday is a holiday in Montreal) and so on.

Could VBA Outlook be the key ? I'm only used to VBA Excel yet.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?  I have no idea what `VBA` is exactly a google result gave me results that had nothing to do with Visual Basic.

Comment: VBA is Visual Basic for Applications which is an adaptation of VB for use with MSO products. I need to do this because we work strictly with business days. Events happen not on the basis of calendar days but on specific business days.